# How do I show text rather than boolean value (Yii2)?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

So I have this form to create a job role and i need to show whether the job role is active or dormant. I am using boolean values 0 and 1 to represent dormant and active. This is my code in the form view (form.php).

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'status')->dropDownList(['1' => 'Active', '0' => 'Dormant'], ['prompt'=>'Select Option']) ?>
```

In my model (Application.php) I have added this function

```
public function getStatusLabel() 
    {
        return $this->status ? 'Active' : 'Dormant';
    }
```

Then in my index.php view I added to display Active/Dormant.

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'], 
            [
                'attribute' => 'Status',
                'value' => 'statusLabel', 
            ],
```

All is working so far. The only problem is that in my view.php (to view each application added) the status is still display 1 and 0. How do I display active/dormant in my view.php too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass this to a function like this:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'], 
        [
            'attribute' => 'Status',
            'value' => function ($data) {
                return $data->getStatusLabel();
            }, 
        ],
```